# klogd using high CPU on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, cpu-usage

One of our servers continues to alert on high CPU.  When looking into this, it is consistently being caused by the klogd process:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
10921 root      20   0  521368  38016    804 S 375.1  0.2 630:10.11 klogd
```

I have looked at other posts such as [klogd using high CPU](https://serverfault.com/questions/165521/klogd-using-high-cpu), but I'm still unable to get to the bottom of this.

strace -p 10921 shows:

```
futex(0x7f24f99619d0, FUTEX_WAIT, 10922, NULL
```

strace -p 10922 shows:

```
futex(0x1c27d44, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 203, NULL
```

strace -p 203 shows:

```
strace: attach: ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ...): No such process
```

Looking at /proc/10921/fd:

```
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jan  9 13:43 5 -> socket:[315987]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jan  9 13:43 4 -> socket:[315944]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jan  9 13:43 3 -> socket:[13077]
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Jan  9 13:43 2 -> /dev/null
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Jan  9 13:43 1 -> /dev/null
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Jan  9 13:43 0 -> /dev/null
```

'ss | grep {any socket above}' does not show any results...

To resolve to date, I generally have been just killing the klogd process.  Sometimes the CPU will start spiking again several hours later with the same klogd command, sometimes it's days later (on a side note, our server reboots nightly - long story...)

Appreciate any help - I'm not a linux sys admin so appreciate any basic tips I am probably overlooking!

Comment: I have seen some old linux kernel bugs that deal with 'FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE'. Can you check if your kernel has that bug?  Also did this problem show up recently? Any other changes in the system?

Comment: The kernel is 3.13.0-29-generic, which is the original from the server build years ago but has always run fine.  Though I'm afraid I know the cause (there was a hack - a bitcoin miner got installed but has been removed and cleaned up to the best of my knowledge), I'm hoping to find troubleshooting tips and confirmation if there is a concern or this is just an issue that can be corrected (Google has many results of this issue in general - but nothing has helped me resolve it yet).  This CPU spike started about a week after the cleanup effort - so unfortunately feels related.

Comment: Also - thanks for the tip.  I am going to explore the kernel update since that is clearly overdue!

Comment: I updated the kernel to the latest (3.13.0-141-generic).  Problem still occurs.  Any other tips appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried starting klogd in debug mode for a bit and see if anything useful is there?

Comment: Thanks again for the help @Tux_DEV_NULL.  I've confirmed this is not really klogd that is running, but rather a process that has somehow been put on this machine and cleverly named klogd - a bitcoin miner.  I can inspect the exe in the /proc folder and see shady http references within the binary.  Now I need to understand how this is being triggered and where from.  I'm digging through the rest of the /proc files now to see if I can find additional clues.